# How to get current visible item in a scrollview [Xamarin.Forms]?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a custom control as a Scrollview that i want to extend with wanting to know when we are at a certain item.

```
public class ExtendedScrollView : ScrollView
{
    public ExtendedScrollView()
    {
        this.Scrolled += ExtendedScrollView_Scrolled;
    }

    private void ExtendedScrollView_Scrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
    {
        double scrollingSpace = this.ContentSize.Height - this.Height;

        if (scrollingSpace <= e.ScrollY)
        {
            // Hits bottom
        }
    }
}
```

I have successfully managed to find the bottom but how can i calculate to see which current view (or views) in the scrollview that are currently being visible?

```
 <controls:ExtendedScrollView>
       <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding service.MyList}">
             <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                       <StackLayout>

                              <controls:CustomControl Data ="{Binding .}" />

                              <BoxView HeightRequest="1"/>

                       </StackLayout>
                  </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
      </StackLayout>
 </controls:ExtendedScrollView>
```

This is how i bind my items to this scrollview successfully. I prefer to use a scrollview, as i have strange issues with the ListView, where it stutters as i scroll down/up.

Comment: What is the strange issues with the ListView ? It would be better to use it as it has the event  `ItemAppearing` and `ItemDisappearing` . You could share your sample with ListView so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: Yea i agree, but i dont know why my listview has issues. I wrap it inside a refreshview. It is stuttering forward.

Comment: You could share your sample .

Comment: I'd rather get the scroll working. Much smoother scroll imo. Performance seems better